# Exporting a Typo3 site bit by bit

Tags: export, typo3

(edit: I'm leaving all the mistaken assumptions in just in case someone else makes the same mistakes)

I have an ancient Typo3 3.8.1 site on a remote server. I don't have access to that server, and the team in charge of maintaining the site doesn't know who to contact to get access to the server. I do have the admin rights on that site, though. (edit: no I don't. oops.)

This is what I see in the (not) admin menu:
[image: the admin menu]

I'm not sure if this version supports extensions, I can't find an extension manager anywhere. (because I'm not an admin)

I want to export the site so I can host it on a server on my own domain instead. The problem is the export file is too large, I can't download it. Will I destroy the directory structure if I export a bunch of pages at a time?

Comment: you do not have an admin Account! So, you will not be able to export TypoScript Templates, extensions etc. You should definitily get an MySQL-Account, an FTP Account or an Shell-Account.

Comment: the one who pays the bills should be able to tell you, who is responsible for the server. Someone should be able to log on that server and give you shell access or a copy of the files and the mysqldump.

Comment: That's not an admin account? Damn. Thing is the guy who set this up is not contactable, and the person in charge of the site now has no idea where the site is or who to contact to get access. Anyway, I've got the web server for the new Typo3 site up and I'm in the middle of exporting the pages from the old site. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the server allows more memory and execution_time that the T3D Export. So, if you can change PHP files on that server, try to change typo3/sysext/impexp/class.tx_impexp.php - search for ini_set and change that settings. If the server allows, you can then create bigger t3d-files.

And you could try some shell-extensions to get hands on that server:

- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/phpshell
- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mw_shell
- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/shell

But to answer your initial question: you can crate a couple of T3D-files and import them again. Just force uid if you import them - and install all needed extensions first!

Comment: Nope, I don't have (and probably can't get) access to the server. I'll give creating multiple t3d files a shot, then. Is there anything I need to take note of when exporting?

Comment: Afaik only when you import: force writing the IDs. The only problem you can get is, that relations are lost. That can hurt, but maybe in that old web does not.

Comment: Okay, I was able to preserve the directory structure by choosing the right page to import under. Now I just need to figure out how to write the templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you have admin access to the backend you can try to install [Quixplorer](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3quixplorer) - file manager. Using it you can try to zip folders in the main directory ie. (`typo3`, `typo3conf`, `fileadmin` etc) one by one and download them via browser.

It's important to download and remove `typo3conf.zip` from the server as soon as possible, cause it contains sensitive data.

Additionally you can also install PhpMyAdmin extension (search in repository) i you haven't other MySQL client.

Edit:

If you can't use Quixplorer the only way is... to write own extension and upload it via Extension Manager, there you'll need to try perform primitive file system operations like:

(PHP)

```
system('zip -R t3c.zip typo3conf/');
```

Comment: Apparently that typo3 install is so old it doesn't support extensions. Damn, it looked like your solution would work too.

Comment: Edited the question to add version number.

Comment: If the website is not big at all why dont u rebuild it in a newer version of Typo3?

Comment: @ArekvanSchayk It's quite big, that's the problem.

Comment: @biesior I don't see the Extension Manager.. Maybe something's weird with this install. I'll post a screenshot of what I see in the admin menu.

Comment: @Seyren - this what you showed on the screenshot is  BE account without `admin` rights, so extension manager is not available for you.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I got the files imported, now I just need to figure out how to write the templates. Getting Typo3 running has been error after error after error, what a pain D: Thanks for the effort!